# Asterisk Realtime Crashing on load when using HAProxy to Galera Cluster

Tags: mysql, mariadb, asterisk, haproxy, galera

Works fine under little load on our test bench but once we add to production the whole thing crashes and we are unable to get asterisk to function correctly. Almost as if there is a lag or delay in accessing the MariaDB cluster.

Our architecture and configs below;

Asterisk 13 Realtime with HAProxy(1.5.18) --> 6 x MariaDB(10.4.11) on independent Datacentres with Galera syncing them (1 only as backup)

Galera Sync is working fine and other services are able to read/write via the HAProxy 100%
Only seems to become and issue when we add load or we reload the dialplan or restart asterisk etc.

```
[haproxy.cfg]

global
    user haproxy
    group haproxy
defaults
    mode http
    log global
    retries 2
    timeout connect 3000ms
    timeout server 10h
    timeout client 10h
listen stats
    bind *:8404
    stats enable
    stats hide-version
    stats uri /stats
listen mysql-cluster
    bind 127.0.0.1:3306
    mode tcp
    option mysql-check user haproxy_check
    balance roundrobin
    server mysql_server1 10.0.0.1:3306 check
    server mysql_server2 10.0.0.2:3306 check
    server mysql_server3 10.0.0.3:3306 check
    server mysql_server4 10.0.0.4:3306 check
    server mysql_server5 10.0.0.5:3306 check
    server mysql_server6 10.0.0.6:3306 check backup
```

Really we would like to know if firstly Asterisk 13 Realtime will work via HAProxy and if so are there config changes we need to make to get it working.

Can provide more info if required

Answer (score 1):

Try use Realtime->ODBC->haproxy.
If not help, use debugging, for example, gdb traces.

There is no way to determine what issue you have. Need more logs and configs.